# Python / Selenium: how to iterate over tr in dynamically-generated table

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary, html-table

I am trying to download the table from this website https://coinmunity.co/ and then manipulate the data in an easy manner with Pandas.
The problem is that the table is dynamically-generated so I cannot easily understand its structure or detect the "tr"s that I need to do a looping job.
I tried with Requests and BeautifulSoup before and did not work, so someone here recommended Selenium, but did not tell me more.

On Selenium I have already tried many things, including xpaths, css selectors,etc...but nothing worked. My idea is to extract the data in an orderly fashion for each row, but the row names seem to have a very strange name including "_ngcontent" and I can't make sense of it.

This is my (non functioning) code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
#driver.get("https://coinmunity.co/")
url = 'file:///C:/Users/nique/PycharmProjects/untitled/test1.html'
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')

#html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

results = []
symbol_list = []

#items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('coin-link')
items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.inner-container > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-child(2)')
#how_many = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('html body app-root app-home div.outer-container div.inner-container table tbody tr')

count = 1
for el in range(1,3):
    #row = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.inner-container > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-child((count))')
    row = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/app-root/app-home/div/div/table/tbody/tr[count]')

    symbol = row.find_element_by_class_name('coin-link')
    followers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('stats')[0]
    changefollowers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('stats')[1]
    # subscribers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('stats')[2]
    # changesubscribers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('stats')[3]
    # price = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('stats')[4]
    # changeprice = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('stats')[5]
    count += 1
    print(symbol)

    # results.append({'Symbol': symbol.text, 'TFollowers': followers.text, 'ChangeFollowers': changefollowers.text,'Subscribers': subscribers.text,'ChangeSubscribers': changesubscribers.text,'Price': price.text, 'ChangePrice': changeprice.text})

print(symbol_list)
print(results)
```

How can I download this information and make it ready for Pandas in the easiest and tidiest possible way? 
Thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly you mean by `extract the data in an orderly fashion for each row`? What are your exact `Manual Steps` which you are trying to `Automate`?

Comment: At this point I am only aiming to download the data in a way I can easily visualize with Pandas, so what I meant was just that I dont' want to overcomplicate things, mainly because I am not an advanced programmer either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two directives to handle the problem you described:

1. **Iterate over all the rows of the table, using `driver.find_elements_by_<something>()`.**
   I'd recommend using this with a static webpage. It's more natural, given the fact that you actually take advantage of Selenium's functions.
2. **Download the webpage's HTML code, parse and manipulate it "offline".**
   This would work better when the page is constantly updating, and will guarantee you don't call stale elements in the page. However it'll force you to parse HTML code, which is never a fun thing to do.

Choose what best for you, and then you can move forward with the more technical issues.
Good luck!

*Edit:* Note how the method is calling element**s**, hence you're not suppose to mention the element's index. So in your case you can use:

```
row = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/app-root/app-home/div/div/table/tbody/tr')

# And not:
row = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/app-root/app-home/div/div/table/tbody/tr[number]')
```

It'll return all the element that have the mentioned property (in this case, the given xpath).

Comment: Could you possibly give me a code example of how to "Iterate over all the rows of the table, using driver.getElements()"? I am not sure what you mean. I am not advanced yet. I guess I would have to put something between the brackets, and that's where I get stuck. What would go in between the "()" in this case? I am confused

Comment: @skeitel I've edited my answer. Let me know how it goes

Comment: All good with the line of code you wrote, @GalAbra. It was the missing piece. Thank you very much! 
But so that I learn...how did you come up with the exact syntax needed to reach the tr we needed? Where can I learn more about it?

Comment: @skeitel I'm glad to hear that! I've been dealing with Selenium for a while now, so I can assure you the best way to learn is to practice and get stuck ;) You can read more about `find_elements_by_...` [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html) or [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html). Good luck!!

Comment: Oh thanks...getting stuck seems to be my specialty...if that's the best way to learn i am going to be very good one day...thanks!